# Why the text is displayed on one line?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Well, I have a problem with my code, I need to download the code from the URL (code: php), using JSOUP on the Android platform. The site looks nice (data is separated by ENTER), and in the application everything is written in one String and I can not adjust it to your needs. Namely, I would like the data from the page to be identically arranged in the application.

```
private void getWebsite(){
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            try {

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://k69.pl/odtwarzacz/aplikacjaRadia.php").get();

                Elements links = ((Document) doc).select("body");


                    for(Element link : links){

                    builder.append(link.attr("<br>")).append(link.text());


                }

            } catch (IOException e){
                builder.append("Aplikacja nie mogła wykonać żądania. Zgłoś ten błąd do administratora aplikacji. Twój błąd to : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
            }


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    wynik.setText(builder.toString());
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();




}
```

Result from the site:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvIbe.jpg

Result from the app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VADVI.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is for HTML so if you are building HTML for a webview that will work fine.
However, you are setting a Text so HTML tags are not understood or obeyed.

Instead for setting text you should be doing

```
builder.append(link.attr("\n")).append(link.text());
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: After changing the code, the text is still written in one sequence on the application.

Comment: That's probably because you are getting the BODY tag and it only has one element. Set a debug point and make sure that you have more than one element in your BODY tag and that you are properly walking the children and not just the body as one element.

Answer (score 0):

```
                try {

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://k69.pl/odtwarzacz/aplikacjaRadia.php").get();

                Elements links = ((Document) doc).select("div");


                    for(Element link : links){

                        builder.append(links.attr("\n")).append(links);
```

Sam, 
I changed the code, now I have such a result (https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Yh9.jpg). How to get rid of this div and br?

link.text() <= causes the text to continue in one line

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, I did it differently and it works as I wanted. Swap Elemens "JSOUP" on String.

```
 for(Element link : links){

                       String tresc = links.toString();

                       String[] x;
                       String zamien;

                       zamien =  tresc.replace("<br>","");
                       x = zamien.split("\n");
```